# How to divide an http response into chunks?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, urllib, download

I'm trying to create a multithreaded downloader using python. Lets say I have a link to a video of size 100MB and I want to download it using 5 threads with each thread downloading 20MB simultaneously. For that to happen I have to divide the initial response to 5 parts which represents different parts of the file (like this 0-20MB, 20-40MB, 40-60MB, 60-80MB, 80-100MB), I searched and found http range headers might help.
Here's the sample code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen,Request
url= some video url
header = {'Range':'bytes=%d-%d' % (5000,10000)} # trying to capture all the bytes in between 5000th and 1000th byte.
req=Request(url,headers=header)
res=urlopen(req)
r=res.read()
```

But the above code is reading the whole video instead of the bytes I wanted and it clearly isn't working. So is there any way to read specified range of bytes in any part of the video instead of reading from the start ? Please try to explain in simple words.

Comment: Multithreading your downloader may not make things faster if the bottleneck is the bandwidth of the connection.

Comment: See the Wikipedia article titled [_Byte serving_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving) about the subject. The `Content-Range` header of the response will tell you what bytes are being delivered.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I just wanna give it a try.

Comment: You've got the article explaining how it works in simple words...go for it!

Comment: I created two headers `h1={'Range':'bytes=%d-%d' %(500,1000)}` and `h1={'Range':'bytes=%d-%d' %(1000,2000)}`  and I passed an image link as url and I executed `urlopen(req).info['Content-Length']` and  `Content-Length`'s were `5001` and `1001` as expected. But when I gave video link as url `Content-Length` for both the headers was same and is equal to the total size of the video ( which it shouldn't ). Same thing happened when I passed [link](http://www.google.com) as url. Is it possible that byte serving only work in some cases ?

Comment: The server many not support what you want to do. "Byte serving begins when an HTTP server advertises its willingness to serve partial requests using the `Accept-Ranges` response header."

Comment: There are downloaders like ADM (for android) which can download content which i'm trying to download, in multithreads. What kind of approach they might have ? As bit serving approach seems to be limited, is there any other way that you could suggest that fit my requirements ?

Comment: "If the range is valid, the server sends it to the client with a 206 Partial Content status code and a Content-Range header listing the range sent." Sorry, this is the only method of which I am aware.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience :) @martineau

Answer (score 1):

> But the above code is reading the whole video instead of the bytes I
>   wanted and it clearly isn't working.

The core problem is the the default request uses the **HTTP GET** method which pulls down the entire file all at once.

This can be fixed by adding `request.get_method = lambda : 'HEAD'`.  This uses the **HTTP HEAD** method to fetch the *Content-Length* and to verify than range requests are supported.

Here is a working example of chunked requests.  Just change the *url* to your url of interest:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

url = 'http://www.jython.org' # This is an example. Use your own url here.

n = 5
request = Request(url)
request.get_method = lambda : 'HEAD'
r = urlopen(request)

# Verify that the server supports Range requests
assert r.headers.get('Accept-Ranges', '') == 'bytes', 'Range requests not supported'

# Compute chunk size using a double negation for ceiling division
total_size = int(r.headers.get('Content-Length'))
chunk_size = -(-total_size // n)

# Showing chunked downloads.  This should be run in multiple threads.
chunks = []
for i in range(n):
    start = i * chunk_size
    end = start + chunk_size - 1  # Bytes ranges are inclusive
    headers = dict(Range = 'bytes=%d-%d' % (start, end))
    request = Request(url, headers=headers)
    chunk = urlopen(request).read()
    chunks.append(chunk)
```

The separate requests in the for-loop can be done in parallel using threads or processes.  This will give a nice speed-up when run in an environment with multiple physical connections to the internet.  But if you only have one physical connection, that is likely to be the bottleneck, so parallel requests won't help as much as expected.

Comment: Off-topic: The comment for `chunk_size = -(-total_size // n)` is pretty worthless. **_Why_** is it being done this way?

Comment: @martineau That is explained in the comment above it.  The double negation computes "ceiling division".  If the *total_size* were 1602 and *n* were 4, you would want the *chunk_size* to be 401 (ceiling division) rather than 400 (floor division) which wouldn't cover the whole dataset (400 * 4 < 1602 <= 401 * 4).